# Unstealable persistent login cookie

Tags: cookies, authentication, autologin

Having read articles like http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice I'm wondering whether there's a reasonably good way to achieve this.

So, what I want is to have a fairly hard time for a crook to steal a cookie, and use it in his own computer. Using secure cookies is out of the question. What I've been thinking about is to hash some information about the user's browser into the cookie, which would be verified once an auto-login is attempt.

So, the problem I'm facing right now is what info to hash. The browser name should be ok, but the version number would invalidate the auto-login on each browser upgrade. The same goes with feature sniffing. What I've been thinking of is hashing the browser name and the user's locale, to get a *reasonable* certain way of counteracting cookie theft.

Am I on the right track? Is there a de-facto way of doing this?

The system doesn't need to be 100% impregnable, just reasonably so.

**PS: You don't have to worry about the other data in the cookie. I'm just curious about the "don't steal this cookie"-part.**

**Edit 1:** A weakness in hashing client info, as I got answered elsewhere, would be that it's enough for the attacker to know that client info is used, and copy the client info as the cookie is stolen. Granted, an additional step to do for the attacker, but not as big a step as I imagined... Any additional thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there aren't any foolproof ways to deal with this, but I'll try to give you a more suitable answer. However, I'll start by some other things you probably should consider.

Start by thing about how to avoid a user's cookie being compromised in the first place. Probably the most common ways of cookie-jacking is either by listening to unsecured HTTP traffic, by using XSS attacks or by exploiting incorrectly defined cookie paths.

You mentioned that secure cookies are out of the question in your case, but I'll want to note this for further reference for other readers. Make sure your site uses HTTPS all the way, this way you will ensure that traffic to your site is secure even if the user is using an unencrypted wireless internet access.

Make sure your site defines the proper domain and path for the cookies, in other words, make sure that the cookies aren't sent to such part of the domain which shouldn't get access to the cookie.

Enable HttpOnly in your cookies. This means that your cookies are only sent on HTTP(S) requests and cannot be read, for example, by using JavaScript. This will mitigate the chances of the user's cookies being stolen by means of XSS.

That said, to answer your actual question, probably a common way of identifying the user by other means is by using browser fingerprints. A browser fingerprint is a hash which is built using unique information to the user's environment, for example, the fingerprint can include browser plugin details, time zone, screen size, system fonts and user agent. Note however, if any of these changes, so does the fingerprint, thus, in your case, invalidating the cookie - I don't necessarily see this as a bad thing, from a security point of view.